solving a HARD recursive formula using generating functions
The recursive formula for the sequence $\{T_n\}$ is as follows:
$$\sum_{\text{$\{a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n\}$ is a partition of $n$}} T_{a_1}\cdot T_{a_2} \cdots T_{a_n} = \frac{2^{n-2}-1}{n!}$$
What is the general formula for $T_n$? Or does there exist a upper bound for $T_n$?
I was thinking about using generating functions to prove it, so basically we have
$$(1+T_1x+(T_1x)^2) \cdot (1+T_2x^2 + (T_2x^2)^2) \cdots = F(x)$$
where $F(x)$ is the exponential generating function of the sequence $\{2^{n-2}-1\}$. Some algebra gives
$$\frac{1}{1-T_1x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-T_2x^2}\cdots = F(x)$$
where $F(x)$ satisfy the differential equation
$$F'(x) = e^x + 2F(x)$$
This means that $F(x) = Ce^{2x}-e^x$ for some C.
However, I am stuck at this point. How can I proceed to find the formula for $T_n$? Or can I prove any bounds? Any insights?

If I were you, I'd try to find $T_1$. Then maybe $T_2$.

@IvanNeretin I calculated $T_1$ through $T_{30}$ and am not sure what you had in mind.

Nothing in particular. Maybe something will transpire if we look at them hard enough. Maybe not.

You write $a_1,\dots,a_n$, which implies that the partition has $n$ parts.  Do you really want that restriction?

An interesting discovery is that if we let $S_n = n! \cdot T_n$, then $S_n$ will form the sequence A000048 on OEIS
